# replacing explicit user names with variables in mkdir and chown

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, chown, mkdir

**What specific changes need to be made in the commands below in order to use a variable username and a variable user_home to create a subdirectory within the current user's home and then to change ownership of the new subdirectory to the current user?**

The current commands we are using in a GitHub ubuntu-lastest runner are too brittle because the following commands use the explicit name of the user:

```
mkdir /home/runner/mysubdirectory/
sudo chown -R runner:runner /home/runner/mysubdirectory/
```

This OP is asking how to replace `/home/runner` with a variable declaration of the current user's home, and how to replace `runner:runner` with variable representations of the current user's name.

Comment: `$USER` refers to the current user.

Comment: And `$HOME` is used to get the user's home directory

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
username=runner
```

```
sudo -Hu "$username" sh -c 'mkdir ~/mysubdirectory'
```

Which runs `mkdir` as the target user (and primary gid of that user) from a shell where `$HOME` has been set to the home directory of that user with `-H` and so where `~` will expand to that.

Or you could invoke `getent` to retrieve the user's information:

```
IFS=: read -r name x uid gid gecos home shell < <(
  getent -- passwd "$username") &&
  sudo install -o "$uid" -g "$gid" -d "$home/mysubdirectory"
```

Comment: A more elegant solution is to use the comments from other users to reduce the command to `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/mysubdirectory/`